# JQuery Token Input with MVC3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am working on JQuery token input, I have followed each step they mentioned in documentation and [Here](http://yassershaikh.com/using-jquery-tokeninput-with-asp-net-mvc-3-razor/)

I am searching courses in autocomplete, and then inserting in database, I am having one problem
For eg if user enter P, it will return Photography and Physics, and add it in list,but user just select anyone(ie Physics)
Now when I  am inserting in database, I am getting both of them in List, I should have the one which user has selected

below is my code

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetSubjects(string subj)
{
    IList searchSubj = Repository1.SearchSubjects(subj);

    foreach (object[] item in searchSchool)
    {
        JsonObjectFlash Model = new JsonObjectFlash();

        Model.id = int.Parse(item[0].ToString());
        Model.name = item[1].ToString();                
        list.Add(Model);
    }

    TempData["id"] = list; //Adding List in TempData to use in inserting

    var jsonResult = list.Select(results => new { id = results.id, name = results.name });    

    return Json(jsonResult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

and while inserting

```
 var lst = (List<JsonObjectFlash>)(TempData["id"]);
```

I am using like '%%' while querying the table

Comment: debug and see what is going in parameter subj when you enter Physics? i think it is going P thats why is returns two records.

Comment: yes its going P, I have to implement FB like taging functionality like when user  type xyz then his friend name appear xyz abc